# Dynamic line wraping- condition based in XSLT1&2

Tags: xslt-2.0

My output type is `text`.
I am preparing for Reports.
My text output got to accept only 50 character width after that which has to be wrapped in to the next line.
I have a solution to line wrap for the elements in the text.
Is there any way to to wrap for the entire reports instead of doing for the every line? 
Can I do it for the whole document?
I have solutions for line wrap, my problem is that I have many conditions like below:

> Firstname lastname route (condition1 ) (condition2) (condition3)
>   (condition4)..go on...

Let us assume:

First name fixedwidth is 15, 
lastname fixed width is 15,city fixed width is 3...

after that condition1 will have 10 width ,condition2 have 15 fixed with then go on...

importantly these conditions are option only...

So 15+emptyspace+15+emptyspace+3 =36 My condition will start from 36 th column..

After the first wrap I got to continue from the same line for the upcoming conditions.
So for the next item i got find the start and end locations.
How to solve this problem ?

xml input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <passengerlist>
      <passengers>
        <Firstname>JOHNNNNNNNNNNNN</Firstname>
        <lastname>MARKKKKKKKKKKKK</lastname>
        <comments>abcdefh abc abcde abc dekf jl</comments>
         <route>air</route>
      </passengers>
    <!-- <passengers>
      <Firstname>ANTONYYYYYYYYYYY</Firstname>
      <lastname>NORMAN</lastname>
      <comments>abcdefddddddddghhhhhhhhhhhhhh</comments>
      <route>air</route>
    </passengers>
    <passengers>
      <Firstname>BRITTOOOOOOOOOO</Firstname>
      <lastname>MARKKKKKKK</lastname>
      <comments>abcdedfffghghghghghghghghghghghghgh</comments>
      <route>cruise</route>
     </passengers> -->
   </passengerlist>
```

XSLT Code:

```
  <!-- For line Wrapping -->

  <xsl:template name="callEmpty">
    <xsl:param name="callEmpty"/>
    <xsl:variable name="LNemptyCheck" select="$callEmpty"></xsl:variable>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template name="text_wrapper">
    <xsl:param name="Text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($Text)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($Text,1,15)"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($Text) &gt; 15">
          <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="wrapper_helper">
          <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="substring($Text,16)"/>   
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="wrapper_helper">
  <xsl:param name="Text"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($Text,1,15)"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="text_wrapper">
    <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="substring($Text,15)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template> 

 <!-- Template for Line wrapping --> 

 <xsl:template match="/">

 <xsl:for-each select="passengerlist/passengers">

   <xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="route"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:variable name="firstwrap">
     <xsl:if test="route='air'">

       <xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/>
       <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="comments"/>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:call-template name="text_wrapper">
      <xsl:with-param name="Text" select="$firstwrap"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
```

Output:

> JOHNNNNNNNNNNNN MARKKKKKKKKKKKK air JOHNNNNNNNNNNNN
>    abcdefh abc ab
>   bcde abc dekf jl
>    MARKKKKKKKKKKKK abcdefh abc ab bcde abc dekf jl

Expected out:

> JOHNNNNNNNNNNNN MARKKKKKKKKKKKK air JOHNNNNNNNNNNNN abcdefh abc ab
>   bcde abc dekf jl MARKKKKKKKKKKKK abcdefh abc abbcde abc dekf jl

Please help me to sort out my problem or tell me Is it possible in XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is (I cannot see any significant difference between output you got and output you expected). But I think it is possible make it simpler. I prepared some testing input xml (just very simple for demonstration).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
    <Line>Some long text is on the first line.</Line>
    <Line>Some longer text is on the second line.</Line>
    <Line>But the longest text occures on the third line.</Line>
</Input>
```

In following xslt I store the result of processing of each line (i.e. copy of its text and append additional text based on some conditions) into a variable. Then I wrap this variable at once using a user function (it could be done with named template as well).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:my="my-ns">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="newLineCharacter" select="'&#10;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="maxLineWidth" select="50" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Input/Line" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Line">
        <!-- Process the line and store the result into variable-->
        <xsl:variable name="processedText">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt;= 1">
                <xsl:text>First condition is true. </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt;= 2">
                <xsl:text>Second condition is true. </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt;= 3">
                <xsl:text>Third condition is true. </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>                   
            <!-- et cetera, et cetera ...-->
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- Wrap the text stored in a variable -->
        <xsl:value-of select="my:wrapText($processedText, $maxLineWidth)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="my:wrapText">
        <xsl:param name="textToBeWrapped" />
        <xsl:param name="maximumWidth" />

        <xsl:value-of select="substring($textToBeWrapped,1,$maximumWidth)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newLineCharacter" />

        <xsl:if test="string-length($textToBeWrapped) &gt; $maximumWidth">
            <!-- Recursive call of my:wrapText to wrap the rest of the text -->
            <xsl:value-of select="my:wrapText(substring($textToBeWrapped,$maximumWidth+1), $maximumWidth)" />
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output is

```
Some long text is on the first line. First conditi
on is true. 
Some longer text is on the second line. First cond
ition is true. Second condition is true. 
But the longest text occures on the third line. Fi
rst condition is true. Second condition is true. T
hird condition is true.
```

I hope it will meet your needs.